# code not behaving as expected when sending each line from a text file to a function as argument

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a file dest.txt which has around 20 morse codes in this format:

```
['. . ... .']
['. . ... -']
['. . -.. .']
['. . -.. -']
['. - ... .']
['. - ... -']
```

My morse decode function works correctly and decodes a morsecode when i assign the morsecode to a variable ex a1=['-.. -- -. -.-. -'] and send a1 as a paramter to the morseDecode function and values is retured as DMNCT.However,in the below code i am trying to loop through the text file and send each line to morsedecode function but output is not as expected.

```
from itertools import product
    def morseDecode(inputStringList):
        message = inputStringList
        #print message
        message = ' '.join(inputStringList)
        message = message + ' '  # adds space at the end of the string message
        #print message
        temp1 = message.replace(".-.-.-", ". ")
        temp2 = temp1.replace(".----.", "' ")
        temp3 = temp2.replace("/", "")
        temp1 = temp3.replace(".... ", "h")
        temp2 = temp1.replace("...- ", "v")
        temp1 = temp2.replace("..-. ", "f")
        temp2 = temp1.replace(".-.. ", "l")
        temp1 = temp2.replace(".--. ", "p")
        temp2 = temp1.replace(".--- ", "j")
        temp1 = temp2.replace("-... ", "b")
        temp2 = temp1.replace("-..- ", "x")
        temp1 = temp2.replace("-.-. ", "c")
        temp2 = temp1.replace("-.-- ", "y")
        temp1 = temp2.replace("--.. ", "z")
        temp2 = temp1.replace("--.- ", "q")
        temp1 = temp2.replace("... ", "s")
        temp2 = temp1.replace("..- ", "u")
        temp1 = temp2.replace(".-. ", "r")
        temp2 = temp1.replace(".-- ", "w")
        temp1 = temp2.replace("-.. ", "d")
        temp2 = temp1.replace("-.- ", "k")
        temp1 = temp2.replace("--. ", "g")
        temp2 = temp1.replace("--- ", "o")
        temp1 = temp2.replace(".. ", "i")
        temp2 = temp1.replace(".- ", "a")
        temp1 = temp2.replace("-. ", "n")
        temp2 = temp1.replace("-- ", "m")
        temp1 = temp2.replace(". ", "e")
        temp2 = temp1.replace("- ", "t")
        result = temp2.upper()
        return result


    def fun():
        with open('dest.txt') as f:
            for line in f:
                a = line
                print morseDecode(a)
        a1=['-.. -- -. -.-. -']
        print morseDecode(a1)


    fun()

    I get the output as :

[ ' TEE  TT  TE  EETE  E' ] 
[ ' TEE  TT  TE  EETE  T' ] 
[ ' TEE  TT  TE  TETE  E' ] 
[ ' TEE  TT  TE  TETE  T' ]
```

What went wrong here.Please help.

Comment: Looks like `morseDecode()` is expecting a list, but you're passing it individual strings. As a result, it puts spaces in between each character of the string, so you end up with nothing but a string of single dots and dashes.

Comment: So how do i insert every line of the text file in a different list,so that i can sendthese lists to morsedecode as argument

Comment: You were right.I read these lines in a list and then the morseDecode function worked like a charm.